# How to capture a dynamic port before a websocket connection closes from "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3003"

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, port

I'm new to the concept of websocket connections and unsure how to approach this problem where the connection closes with an e.reason `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3003`. I can only assume there is a websocket proxy function in the server that provides an open port from the default websocket connection port 3000.

I am trying to make a new websocket connection with a predefined websocket url `ws://localhost:3000/`

```
var websocket_url = ws://localhost:3000/...

const websocket = new WebSocket(websocket_url);

websocket.addEventListener("open", function(e){
console.log('websocket open', e.target);
});

websocket.addEventListener("message", function(e){
console.log('websocket message', e.target);
});

websocket.addEventListener("close", function(e){
console.log('websocket closed', e.reason);
});
```

Unfortunately, the websocket connection closes with a log: `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3003`.
What are best practices to prefetch the dynamic port before it fails to connect; because when I manually type port 3003, it works.

Comment: "ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3003" means there is nothing that listens on port 3003. There is not network socket bound to the interface/ip and that port.